# DropDownList not showing SelectedValue in MVC Razor .net

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor, dropdown

I attempt to create the dropdown list in the View. The dropdown list for `"CD_STATE_CLASS"` `"IN_DIVIDED"` is working but for `"TOLL_ROAD"`, it can return option values in the dropdown list, but the selected value defined in the function is not presented.When I log the `TOLL_ROAD` in the console, i can see the value but not in the dropdown list. I have no idea where the problem is because code looks identical. And also, when i save the form, it seems like selected `TOLL_ROAD` value in the dropdown list is not passing to the `Road` object.

```
private void GetEditRoadSelectLists(Road road)
{
    var roadLookup = objMgr.GetRoadLookupDataBAL();

    ViewBag.RoadTypes = roadLookup.RoadTypeLookup;
    ViewData["CD_STATE_CLASS"] = new SelectList(roadLookup.StateClassLookup, "StateClassCode", "StateClassDescription", road.CD_STATE_CLASS);
    ViewData["IN_DIVIDED"] = new SelectList(roadLookup.YesNoLookup, "YesNoShort", "YesNoLong", road.IN_DIVIDED);
    ViewData["TOLL_ROAD"] = new SelectList(roadLookup.TollLookup, "Id","TOLL_ROAD", road.RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD);

    //ViewData["TOLL_ROAD"] = new SelectList(roadLookup.TollLookup, "TOLL_ROAD", "TOLL_ROAD", road.RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("toll"+road.RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("YES" + road.IN_DIVIDED);
}
```

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CD_STATE_CLASS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("CD_STATE_CLASS", null, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CD_STATE_CLASS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.DropDownList("TOLL_ROAD", null, "-- Please select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
    
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: TOLL_ROAD does not have pre-defined value]

Comment: @hej I think for better understanding you should share more code, I think you would use dropdownlistfor with model binding.

Comment: @WaqarNaeem hi. I figured it out. It turns out ```TOLL_ROAD``` is supposed in the ```RoadsRamps``` object,  I change the code to ```RoadsRamps.TOLL_ROAD``` then it works.